# How do add an IPA transcription with the vowel sound /ɜː/ without it becoming /ɜːr/

Tags: wikipedia

I'm adding an IPA transcription of a city with an odd pronunciation that foreigners (but still English speakers) hardly every get right.

```
({{IPAc-en|'|k|r|æ|n|,|b|ɜː|n}})
```

becomes `/ˈkrænˌbɜːrn/` rather than `/ˈkrænˌbɜːn/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it to

> ({{IPA-all|'kræn,bɜːn}})

IPAc-en automatically changes the input characters to match American English IPA transcription. "-fr" is for french IPA-all can be used for regional varieties.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:IPA